# Want to match string but getting: TypeError: Cannot use instance of on a non-object

Tags: javascript

Want to match string but getting:

> TypeError: Cannot use instance of on a non-object

I am trying to adapt the following script:

https://rickpastoor.com/2019/05/30/google-calendar-color-coder.html

```
function ColorEvents() {

  var today = new Date();
  var nextweek = new Date();
  nextweek.setDate(nextweek.getDate() + 7);
  Logger.log(today + " " + nextweek);

  var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars();
  Logger.log("found number of calendars: " + calendars.length);

  for (var i=0; i<calendars.length; i++) {
    var calendar = calendars[i];
    var events = calendar.getEvents(today, nextweek);
    for (var j=0; j<events.length; j++) {
      var e = events[j];
      var title = e.getTitle();
      if ("[TEST]" in title[0]) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREY);
      }
      if (title[0] == "!") {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
      }
      if (title[0] == '#') {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run it I get error:

> TypeError: Cannot use instance of on a non-object. (line 17, file
>   "ColorCode")

This is esssentially the line "if ("[TEST]" in title[0]) {"

I would like a match on title[0] if it contains the string "[TEST]"

Comment: you could use `title[0].indexOf("[TEST]") > -1` which would mean that the string "[TEST]" is present in test[0] if the condition is true

Comment: [String#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: @shrys this doesn't match properly but no error is given

Comment: is `title[0]` a string or array of strings?

Comment: I am not sure. How would I know this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve but you're totally misusing [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) which is supposed to be used only for object (and your *title[0]* seems to be a string). If you're trying to check if your string contains other substring, use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: What does the line need to be when using includes() ?

Comment: if (title[0].includes("[TEST]")) {

Comment: That gives error: TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object P. (line 17, file "ColorCode")

Comment: I suspect this is a Google Script error I am encountering